# Invalid command 'bdist_msi' when trying to create MSI installer with 'cx_Freeze'

Tags: python, windows-installer

I am trying to create MSI installer for Windows with `cx_Freeze` package. Anyway, when running command `python setup.py bdist_msi` I get an error that it is invalid. Is there any options I am missing or maybe I cannot use it on Linux (I am using Debian 11)?

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

company_name = '...'
product_version = '...'
product_name = '...'
product_description = '...'

base = None
build_exe_options = {}
bdist_msi_options = {
    'initial_target_dir': r'[ProgramFilesFolder]\%s\%s' % (company_name, product_name),
}

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup(
    name=product_name,
    version=product_version,
    description=product_description,
    options={
        'build_exe': build_exe_options,
        'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options
    },
    executables=[Executable(
        'app.py',
        base=base,
        shortcut_name=product_name,
        shortcut_dir='DesktopFolder',
        icon=str(Path(__file__).parent / 'icon.jpg')
    )],
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#freezing-for-other-platforms) section of cx_Freeze documentation cross compilation is indeed not possible. At least in the usual way.

> cx_Freeze works on Windows, Mac and Linux, but on each platform it
> only makes an executable that runs on that platform. So if you want to
> freeze your programs for Windows, freeze it on Windows; if you want to
> run it on Macs, freeze it on a Mac.
>
> At a pinch, you can try to make a Windows executable using Wine. Our
> experience is that you need to copy some files in manually after
> cx_Freeze has run to make the executable work. We don’t recommend this
> option.